# Near-Fields or Secondary Monitors?

Tags: speakers, monitors, headphones, systems

I'm curious if anyone else uses a smaller speaker system or near-fields along with your main monitors to mix or cut effects on.

What are you all working on?

Answer (score 2):

[Genelec  2029A's](https://web.archive.org/web/20150508113046/http://www.genelec.com:80/products/previous-models/2029a/) at home.

[Genelec 8030A's](https://www.genelec.com/studio-monitors) with [Genelec 7070A's](https://www.genelec.com/studio-monitors/classic-studio-monitors-subwoofers) at work.

[Beyerdynamic DT770Pro 250 ohms](https://web.archive.org/web/20081203135058/http://www.beyerdynamic.de:80/en/music-performance/products/headphones.html?tx_sbproductdatabase_pi1[showUid][showUID]=44) at home and work.

[image: Genelec 8030A]
<sub>(source: [genelec.com](http://www.genelec.com/documents/images/products/8030a.jpg))</sub>

Comment: I love Genelecs.

Answer (score 2):

I have my mains (which are nearfields) plus a few different secondary systems.  I use JBL LSRs as my mains, then I have my rig hooked up to a consumer home theater system in the neighboring room, a pair of Altec Lansing speakers, an assortment of headphones, etc...  I also like listening to any music I do on my car system, since I know that one the best when it comes to music...

I always try to figure out what my listener is going to be listening on and try to mimic that with what I have to hear the end result.

Also, when it comes to editing, I often put on phones to hear the minute details of what I'm working on.  Things that might not come through as well on my mains.

Comment: Yeah, that was Ezra Dweck.  Crazy Stuff...

http://www.colinhartonline.com/?p=91

Answer (score 1):

My room isn't big enough for anything other than nearfields. Working in the UK, I use BBC LS 3/5a speakers with a small active sub to supplement the low end and it works well. On the road I either take a pair of the BBC boxes or use my Sony MDR-709 headphones.

Answer (score 1):

In my mix studio I have a pair of ATC SCM100s but I always spot check my work on the TV and in mono. I don't check my work in lots of places as I don't have time. I did some checking like that when I started work here but now I just trust that what I do will work as I know how my mixes sound elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The Avantone Mix Cubes are my mono and real-world reference of choice.

--jpf

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 studios with Adam P11's and a small studio with Genelec 8020's.

At home I have nothing but Sennheiser HD-650 headphones, so I rarely work from home.